# How to deploay an webservice in azure from binaries

Tags: .net, azure, web-applications

Is there an option to deploy a azure web app (webservice) from binaries instead of using the publisher profile in visual studio?

I have a deploymend ready webservice which needs to be deployed in azure.

The scope of the webservice is, that each customer can host this (with a small instruction) in his own azure tenand.

So the goal would be to just put in a .zip with the soapservice (wsdl, xml, binaries, etc.. ). Is this on some way possible to configure?

Comment: Well, you can go to `https://yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net` -> Debug console -> CMD -> go to /site/wwwroot -> Drag-and-drop zip file to the right edge of the file listing -> zip gets unpacked automatically

Comment: @juunas  this is really simple, never mind. Publishing is done, but how to I address my service endpoint ? is not not hosted yet? 
I use https://<Appname>.azurewebsites.net/Service1.svc?wsdl , but the file is not found :/

Comment: If it is wwwroot with the proper web.config, it should at least serve the files. Not sure if you need some additional config with this.

Comment: found my error. I published the release folder, instead of just publishing a new zip from the webservice, where no subfolder is included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to https://yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net -> Debug console -> CMD -> go to /site/wwwroot -> Drag-and-drop your files as a zip file to the right edge of the file listing -> the zip file gets unpacked automatically.

This is perhaps the easiest way to "just deploy files".
You can read more on it from for example here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/12/28/deploy-to-an-azure-app-service-using-kudu-and-a-zip-file/.

For a more repeatable deployment, I do suggest automating the process and using either WebDeploy, FTP, ZipDeploy, or the local Git repository to do deployments.